# wpdb & wp_query order by return wrong values

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

i wanna get results from wp_postmeta order by DESC their values.i use this codes :

```
$top_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'sd_top_numbers' ORDER BY meta_value DESC");
foreach ($top_query as $details) {
    echo $details->meta_value;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

output!

```
8800
8900
9600
9700
15700
16200
```

i also try wp_query but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$top_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'sd_top_numbers' ORDER BY meta_value + 0 DESC");
```

Use order by `meta_value`  if you order by `meta_key` and all your records have meta_key equals to sd_top_numbers, then values would be unordered. (The fact they are ordered here is just coincidence).

`+ 0` here converts strings to numeric values and then orders them.

Comment: it occurs when some numbers +10000 and some numbers are -10000 , if i enter numbers that all are -10000 or +10000 wpdb return true values i dont know why , i registed metabox by metabox.io plugin last version

Comment: Its caused because the `meta_value` you check is string.  therefore you cannot compare them as numbers.  I have edited the answer to make conversion to ints. This should work now.

Comment: yeah u right but doesnt work + 0 , is there another way to compare numbers?

Comment: But the problem is `meta_value` is not a number. In the table `meta_value` is TEXT. That means its string. If you compare strings then numeric comparision is not used but instead string one. for example 1 is before -1 as `-` asci code is higher than asci code for `1` therefore `1` is before and whole `-1`. 

That ` + 0` makes sure database for ordering would convert (what it can) to numbers and then use converted values.

Comment: Just remember not to use it when you order by numeric column types.  for example post_id or other ids.^^

Comment: btw can i + 0 for wp_query or somthing like this ?

Comment: I dont know for truth... You can always make sorting in php instead of dabase if that is not possible. I normally write my own queries when i need to order something that ,,wasnt designed'' by wordpress normally.

So really sorry but i cannot answer you that.

Comment: oh my god php sorting , yes it solves all my problems to sort values without any headache like this , so i ll get all values then sort them i dont know how to thank seti